# Socket implementation with micropython and WIZNET5500

Tags: sockets, networking, ethernet, micropython, lwip

i'd like to ask how to bind sockets properly. I have problem with binding socket to Ethernet modul W5500 for arduino and listening raw packets.I cant understand why i am getting error with binding. During compilation, binding returns OSError: [Errno 5] EIO.
My code is:

```
from machine import Pin,SPI
import network
import time
import lwip

#W5x00 chip init
def w5x00_init():
    spi = SPI(0,2_000_000, mosi=Pin(19),miso=Pin(16),sck=Pin(18))
    nic = network.WIZNET5K(spi,Pin(17),Pin(20)) #spi,cs,reset pin
    nic.active(True)
    nic.ifconfig(('192.168.0.1','255.255.255.0','',''))
    
    print(nic.ifconfig())

    return nic
        
def main():
    nic = w5x00_init()
    
    s = lwip.socket(lwip.AF_INET,lwip.SOCK_RAW,lwip.IPPROTO_IP)
    
    s.bind(("192.168.0.1",0))
    
  # s.listen(5)
    
    while(1):
        
      #  conn, addr = s.accept()
        
        #data, addr = s.recvfrom(1508)

        time.sleep(1)
   
        
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I wanted to bind ip of ethernet to socket and receive coming raw packets

type here